# How can we stay on top of old questions? / Guidelines for old questions

Tags: discussion, moderators, unanswered-questions

Last night (Around this time) I went through the Unanswered Questions from the bottom up. I got through till page 3 only choosing questions that the user who asked had shown recent activity or more reputation than the inactive-asker.  I realized that this should definitely be something that we should regularly pay attention to.

Pro Webmasters is one of the lowest answer-rate sites on SE. I think with just some paying attention and follow-up comments to make sure the question was answered, we can increase our answer-rate as well as encourage users to come to Pro Webmasters for their questions.

Although it doesn't take long to go through the questions of old and add a comment, we should establish some guidelines about:

- What reputation required for a follow-up comment
- How long ago dubs it 'Old'
- What should be discarded
- How to respond

I have gotten 3 responses so far, 2 of them the user found the answer already and posted it, and the third I put a bounty on. This shouldn't be a responsibility for only the Moderators. We all can chip in and make Pro Webmasters just that much better.

---

#### EDIT

I want to expand this question to include a discussion on Guidelines for old questions that need to be deleted and / or when to give a 'poke' (Add a comment) to the user letting them know that their question does not have an answer chosen. Here is a few ideas on the criteria for both.

Before I continue, allow me to clarify this 'poke.' Adding a comment to the question asking the user whether or not a method worked that was presented or if they have found a solution that wasn't originally presented. Or, if you have a solution that didn't occur to you when the question was presented

***Questions to be deleted* criteria:**

- Closed questions 'linger' for 3 days,
  then are deleted. These include questions that have been migrated to another site.
- Questions can be '[protected](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/protect-questions)' to halt the deletion process and allow that question to stay.

  > Just in case there is a question that for some reason we would like to stay in Pro Webmasters. Perhaps to prevent further duplicates.

***Questions to be revisited* criteria:**

- User asking the question must have above 100 reputation.

  > This might seem odd to some, however I felt it necessary as giving a comment to notify the user that his/her question is still unanswered is useless if they never come back. Having a reputation of above 100 (Especially for the really old questions) is a good indicator that the particular user visits Pro Webmasters or anyother Stack Exchange website decently often.
- Question must be 5 days old.

  > This is there because before 5 days, the question can typically still be viewed at the top of the second page of questions, in which can still receive above negligible views.
- Poorly worded questions should be avoided or commented for clarification.

  > In order to have well-formed questions that people can search for.

I'm looking for suggestions or to get a good discussion going about some guidelines. The ones I have posted are just suggestions themselves and can change. I want to get this question up to the SE team for some tweaks to the site.

Comment: Any more great additions to this like Jeff's? I'm going to pack it up and send it to the StackExchange team to see what they think soon. Any / all input is welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Excellent! You might also be interested in

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review

which will highlight posts by new users, primarily.

In general, I suggest answering any questions, even old ones, that you feel are interesting and can be interesting to others. There is value in answering questions that have nad no recent activity -- this bumps the question naturally, and if I see a good answer, I will *always* upvote it, regardless of how old the question is.

However, this assumes the original question is interesting enough for me to click on in some way -- if it's a really bad question (title, etc) or an extremely obscure topic. However, this can often be fixed with editing.

Thus, now that [we have anonymous and low-rep edit suggestions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/), **I would "punch up" the question as well when answering**, to maximize the chances of people seeing both the question *and* your (excellent, of course) answer.

Comment: Great suggestion Jeff. So you're saying take a gander at old questions every now and then for questions that peak your interest? And thank you for that link - didn't know about that.

Comment: @chris in general don't hesitate to edit the question to make it better. And note [we automatically cull zero and negatively voted questions over time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), so don't feel obligated to clean up too much -- just make the salvageable ones better!

Comment: Since the unanswered section also lists questions with no upvoted answers, it's a good idea to vote up any good answers you see in the section.

Answer (score 0):

What about questions which are bumped up from `Community` which were asked by a member who's no longer a user on SE. An example is this question which was just bumped up [Apache http.conf allow intranet](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19501/apache-http-conf-allow-intranet)

It was asked in 2011 and the user doesn't have a profile. Since no answer can be selected if it stays it'll be left up to the community to up vote the best answers.